# Changing the style of default emails in odoo 16

Tags: odoo, email-templates, odoo-16

I wanted to change the style of default odoo e-mails such as purchase invoice e-mail in odoo 16, but I encountered problems:

1- I wanted to give a direction rtl to the email code, for example, sent for Order Confirmation, so that the text of the email becomes rtl, but when sending the email, the direction rtl is deleted and the email is corrupted. Even in the preview that shows this style is visible, but it disappears when sending.

2- If I want to give a special style to the Sales: Order Confirmation email, how should I add it?

In the part of the code, when I add the style using the style tag, it will be removed again when sending.

I also tested it as an inline style, but Odoo comes and deletes my style when sending

Comment: Are you applying style on mail template ?

Comment: did you find out why this was an issue?